# If I use third party crash-analytics sdk in my production app , will it suppress my iTunes-Crash Report?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

My app is now going on to production phase. If I use third party **crash**-analytics sdk in my production app , will it **suppress** my iTunes-Crash Report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple will always get crash reports. Apples crash reporter runs out-of-process, all 3rd party crash reporting solutions run inside your apps process. Depending on the quality of the 3rd party crash reporter implementation, Apples crash reports may not have the best quality.

There are some crash reports that you will only get from iTunes Connect which is basically all that are technically app kills and not crashes, e.g. when your app blocks the main thread too long, or if it takes too long to launch or exit the app.

One difference is that you may not get access to every single crash report from Apple and it is unknown when they show reports and if they do any sampling or similar. Crash reports will also only be sent to Apple, if the user agrees to share this information in general when setting up the device or changing the according setting in the settings app. There are reports that only about about 30% of device users activate this settings. The amount may vary by app and can of course also yield in bigger percentages.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't. I have Fabric with Crashlytics installed in various apps and I still see the reports in iTunes Connect.